# Max Length of ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong()

Tags: java, multithreading, random

I'm planning to use ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong() to generate IDs across various threads. The application's criteria is to have 19 digits numeric value. We used System.nanoTime() before with padding but lately its been generating same IDs.

I tried using ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong() and it's generating 19 digits long value. Is the value for it always 19 digits or it can be less than 19 digits too? And is it safe to use between multiple threads?

Comment: What does the javadoc of nextLong() say?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`nextLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextLong--) says only: "Returns a pseudorandom `long` value".  The documentation for `nextLong(long bound)` says: "Returns a pseudorandom `long` value between zero (inclusive) and the specified bound (exclusive)." Thus, `bound` can be as high as 9223372036854775807, which is a 19-digit number.

However, the documentation for `ThreadLocalRandom` says nothing about its state size or a guaranteed period length, nor does it mention what algorithm the method uses internally.  Thus, it might not have the quality you need for ID generation.

Instead, consider using a cryptographic RNG, such as `java.security.SecureRandom`, for ID generation.  But first, think about why you need to generate IDs.  Do the IDs have to be unique?  Do they have to be hard to guess?  Can you just use sequential numbers instead?  You should answer the six questions I give in "[Unique Random Identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers)", so you can find out how best to generate unique IDs in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply specify the range you want? For example, if you only want your random IDs to be 12 digits long, just use the following:

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(100000000000L, 899999999999L)
```

Also, according to the java doc it should be safe to use with multiple threads:

> Use of ThreadLocalRandom is particularly appropriate when multiple
>   tasks (for example, each a java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask (JDK
>   1.7)) use random numbers in parallel in thread pools.